# Adding button below listview not working whereas adding above is working fine in android

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I want to add two buttons bellow list view but it is not working, whereas if i add those buttons above list it is working fine why?

**error log:**

```
03-28 07:24:23.610: I/dalvikvm-heap(3296): Grow heap (frag case) to 4.215MB for 1127536-byte allocation
03-28 07:24:23.650: D/dalvikvm(3296): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3K, 5% free 4248K/4428K, paused 33ms, total 34ms
03-28 07:24:23.790: D/AndroidRuntime(3296): Shutting down VM
03-28 07:24:23.790: W/dalvikvm(3296): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb1a3bba8)
03-28 07:24:23.810: E/AndroidRuntime(3296): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-28 07:24:23.810: E/AndroidRuntime(3296): Process: com.example.ex3dynamiclist, PID: 3296
03-28 07:24:23.810: E/AndroidRuntime(3296): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ex3dynamiclist/com.example.ex3dynamiclist.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Button cannot be cast to android.widget.ListView
03-28 07:24:23.810: E/AndroidRuntime(3296):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
03-28 07:24:23.810: E/AndroidRuntime(3296):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
03-28 07:24:23.810: E/AndroidRuntime(3296):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
03-28 07:24:23.810: E/AndroidRuntime(3296):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
03-28 07:24:23.810: E/AndroidRuntime(3296):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-28 07:24:23.810: E/AndroidRuntime(3296):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-28 07:24:23.810: E/AndroidRuntime(3296):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
03-28 07:24:23.810: E/AndroidRuntime(3296):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-28 07:24:23.810: E/AndroidRuntime(3296):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-28 07:24:23.810: E/AndroidRuntime(3296):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
03-28 07:24:23.810: E/AndroidRuntime(3296):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
03-28 07:24:23.810: E/AndroidRuntime(3296):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-28 07:24:23.810: E/AndroidRuntime(3296): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Button cannot be cast to android.widget.ListView
03-28 07:24:23.810: E/AndroidRuntime(3296):     at com.example.ex3dynamiclist.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment.onCreateView(MainActivity.java:64)
03-28 07:24:23.810: E/AndroidRuntime(3296):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
03-28 07:24:23.810: E/AndroidRuntime(3296):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
03-28 07:24:23.810: E/AndroidRuntime(3296):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
03-28 07:24:23.810: E/AndroidRuntime(3296):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
03-28 07:24:23.810: E/AndroidRuntime(3296):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
03-28 07:24:23.810: E/AndroidRuntime(3296):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:570)
03-28 07:24:23.810: E/AndroidRuntime(3296):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1171)
03-28 07:24:23.810: E/AndroidRuntime(3296):     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5241)
03-28 07:24:23.810: E/AndroidRuntime(3296):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2168)
03-28 07:24:23.810: E/AndroidRuntime(3296):     ... 11 more
03-28 07:24:26.240: I/Process(3296): Sending signal. PID: 3296 SIG: 9
```

**.XML FILE**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.ex3dynamiclist.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/mobile_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/addBtn"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="addItems"
            android:text="Add Item" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/removeBtn"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="removeItems"
            android:text="Remove selected" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

.JAVA FILE

```
package com.example.ex3dynamiclist;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Adapter;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.os.Build;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        String[] mobileArray = {"Android","IPhone","WindowsMobile","Blackberry","WebOS","Ubuntu","Windows7","Max OS X","Max OS X","Max OS X","Max OS X","Max OS X","Max OS X","Max OS X","Max OS X","Max OS X","Max OS X","Max OS X","Max OS X"};
        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(rootView.getContext(),R.layout.activity_listview, mobileArray);
            ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.mobile_list);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

    public void addItems(View view){
        Log.d("DEBUG","Add Items Reached");
    }

    public void removeItems(View view){
        Log.d("DEBUG","Remove Items Reached");
    }

}
```

Comment: post your java file..!!

Comment: Clean and rebuild project  check this line ClassCastException: android.widget.Button cannot be cast to android.widget.ListView.

Comment: The problem is `at com.example.ex3dynamiclist.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment.onCreateView(MainActivity.java:64)`. Could you share your onCreate method? Probably, you are depending on the order of the children inside the linearlayout. Instead, access the listview using its id.

Comment: Give weight 1 to android:id="@+id/LinearLayout2"

Comment: yes!! @Rohit but now half place is covered with list and half with button??

Comment: remove this line from the list view android:layout_weight="1"  and put layout weight sum for linear layout of buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the below xml code and it will surely work.

**Explanation**

you have first added the listview and then the buttons and that make the confusion about the height in the layout. so first add the buttons and then the listview.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="bottom"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.listviewinsidescrollview.Main2Activitytryyyy"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main2_activitytryyyy">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addBtn"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:text="add item" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="remove item"
        android:id="@+id/removeBtn" />
</LinearLayout>

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_list"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/LinearLayout2"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: glad i am able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Change parent LinearLayout to RelativeLayout, change mobile_list's and LinearLayout2's height's to wrap_content, remove weight from mobile_list and add

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

to LinearLayout2. Like below:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"

tools:context="com.example.ex3dynamiclist.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/mobile_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addBtn"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="addItems"
        android:text="Add Item" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/removeBtn"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="removeItems"
        android:text="Remove selected" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your xml file should have something like below code

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.ex3dynamiclist.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/mobile_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="0.8" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:layout_weight="0.2">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/addBtn"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="addItems"
            android:text="Add Item" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/removeBtn"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="removeItems"
            android:text="Remove selected" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Rest assign the button and listview ids correctly in your fragment. And set onClickListeners and adapter as and how needed.
Also if you want to place the buttons above listview , just cut the linear layout containing the two button and paste it above listview.